# Where does the $-u$ come from when working out $P(U > u)$?

Tags: self-study, exponential-distribution

> The lifetime of a machine is modelled by an exponential random variable $X$ with $P(X>x) = e^{-\lambda x}, \lambda, x > 0$. This machine cannot be repaired. A maintenance crew checks this machine at times $T, 2T, 3T, ...., $ where $T$ is a specified length of time
>
> Consider the events $A_k=\{(k-1)T < X  \leq kT\}$ and denote $U$ the duration of the time when the machine is down before it is discovered to be down. Then use the formulas
>
> $$EU = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} E(U |A_k)P(A_k)$$
>
> and
>
> $$E(U|A_k) = \int_0^{T} P(U > u |A_k) du$$
>
> to find the expected duration of the time when the machine is down before it is discovered to be down.

In the answers, it says $P(U > u) = P\{(k - 1)T < X \leq kT - u\}$ but I don't get why it is $kT - u$. Why is it not $(k - 1)T + u$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U$ is the amount of time the machine is down before it's discovered, i.e., the difference between the time $X$ the machine goes down and the time $kT$ at which it is next checked[1]: $U = kT-X$ Thus, $P(U = u) = P(kT-X = u)$. Rearranging terms, we get  $P(X = kT-u)$.

The inequalities come when we move from $P(U=u)$ to $P(U > u)$, but the right-hand side of the inequality stays the same.

[1] I'm implicitly conditioning on the fact that $(k-1)T < X < kT$, just to make things clearer.